# Flask and Cx_Freeze module object has no attribute rfind

Tags: flask, cx-freeze

i've an issue with my code, may be one of you will be able to help me about this

here is my script.py :

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import jinja2.ext

import webbrowser

def main():
    from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, \
        request, url_for,escape, session
    from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
    app = Flask(__name__)
    webbrowser.open_new_tab('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
    Bootstrap(app)

    @app.route('/')
    def home():
      return render_template('home.html')


    @app.route('/choice')
    def choice():
      return render_template('Choice.html')


    @app.route('/src&dest')
    def GenerationPage():
      return render_template('generate.html')


    @app.route('/success')
    def successfull():
      return render_template('success.html')


    return app.run(debug=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and my setup.py :

```
import sys
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

path = sys.path + ["src", "src/templates"]

includes = [sys, os]
excludes = []
packages = []

include_files = ['templates']


options = {"path": path,
           "includes": includes,
           "excludes": excludes,
           "include_files": include_files
           }

if sys.platform == "win32":
  options["include_msvcr"] = True


base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
   base = "Win32GUI"


FirstTarget = Executable(
   script="Other.py",
   base=base,
   compress=False,
   copyDependentFiles=True,
   appendScriptToExe=True,
   appendScriptToLibrary=False
   )

setup(
   name="FlaskTrapeze",
   version="0.1",
   description="Ouvre une interface web",
   author="Axel M",
   options={"build_exe": options},
   executables=[FirstTarget]
   )
```

I'm facing this issue when I try to build it under windows

"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rfind'"

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Some problems in your question: 1. take care of your indentation, it's important in python; 2. post the full error log instead of one line would be more helpful.

Comment: post your file structure. I believe cx_freeze expects an `__init__.py` in every module

Comment: It's the line `includes = [sys, os]` - it needs the names of modules as strings, like `'sys'`, not the modules themselves. sys and os should both be included automatically, though, so you shouldn't need to put them there.

Comment: Thanks, it was that Thomas !